# Laravel: External variable in callback for chunk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement **search** in Laravel. I want to search on models.
Since there can be many records in the database, I am trying the `chunk` function.

```
public function searchLeads($param)
    {
        $results = array();

        // get all leads
        Lead::chunk(100, function($leads) use ($results, $param) {
            // search in name
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInName($leads, $param));

            // search in email
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInEmail($leads, $param));

           // and so on ...
    }

    // eliminate duplicates
    $collection = collect($results);
    $collection = $collection->unique();

    $results = $collection->all();

    dd($results);
    // return $results;
}
```

Note: The `searchIn...` functions return array of results and are working as expected.

When I try the above code, I get an empty array. So I changed the following line (added a reference `&` to `$results`).

```
Lead::chunk(100, function($leads) use (&$results, $param) {
```

Now I get the expected output.

My **question** is, have I stumbled upon the right solution, or am I missing something that might introduce bugs in the code?

**Note:**
I know using `where clause` is a better and efficient way; but I cannot use `where` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution after reading a bit about `php closures`. My real worry was that I am not using the `$results` array correctly.

But after reading [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), I know I am doing it correctly.

Please note that I am aware of `where` clause and it's usage would be much more efficient here. But that's not what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

to use the search, you could do something like:

```
$results = Lead::where('mail','like', $param)->orWhere('name','like', $param)->get();
```

then mysql does the search, which i believe is the fastes way of doing it.

depending on how the search should be done:

```
...where('mail','like', %$param%)...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

else try to describe what the end goal of your search is?

Comment: What you suggest is correct. But that's not what I wanted to ask. It's my fault; I didn't clarify myself in the question. I cannot use where clauses as the search is being conducted on derived and related fields which cannot be directly converted to an SQL query.